# is $x^{100000000000}$ a "polynomial time"?

Tags: polynomial-time

per this [post](https://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/np-complete.html)

> $t = x^2$ means the problem is solvable in "Polynomial" time.

per this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3253951/673047)

> in the form
>
> $$a_{n}x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dotsb +a_{2}x^{2}+a_{1}x+a_{0} {
> > \boldsymbol{=0}}$$
>
> plug in $n=100000000000$ with $a_n=1$ and $a_k=0$ for all $k \neq n$
>
> then we see that $x^{100000000000}$ is a polynomial
>
> it doesn't matter if its 2, 3, or a billion, as long as the n is a finite number

in this context, does $t = x^{100000000000}$ still mean the problem is solvable in "Polynomial" time?

Comment: I suggest you read up on what a [polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial) is.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is not about CS but rather about basic math terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $x^{100000000000}$ is a polynomial. Your first quote gives an example; your second is the definition.